# I am using ifstream and I need to read in two words as one string instead of splitting them

Tags: c++, ifstream

I need to read in a line from a file, but I need to save two strings as one. For example, if the file's line had someone's name like `Bernie Sanders`, I would want to save the entire name into a string variable instead of just the first name.

Comment: `inputstream >> first >> last; std::string name = first + ' ' + last;`?

Comment: Or, use `std::getline()` instead: `std::getline(inputstream, name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are doing

```
  std::string nameString;
  fs >> nameString;
```

this will read to the end of a word.
do this instead

```
 std::string nameString;
 std::getline(fs, nameString);
```

this will read the whole line